# Python function minimisation without derivative

Tags: python, scipy, derivative, minimization

I am familiar with some of the functions in scipy.optimize.optimize and have in the past used fmin_cg to minimize a function where I knew the derivative. However, I now have a formula which is not easily differentiated.

Several of the functions in that module (fmin_cg, for instance) do not actually require the derivative to be provided. I assume that they then calculate a quazi-derivative by adding a small value to each of the parameters in turn - is that correct?

My main question is this: Which of the functions (or one from elsewhere) is the best to use when minimising a function over multiple parameters with no given derivative?

Comment: You are correct about the method of approximating the derivative (Jacobian) numerically.  I have seen this when using `scipy.optimize.leastsq`.

Comment: Just curious, how many variables do you have ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, calling any of `fmin_bfgs fmin_cg fmin_powell` as

```
fmin_xx( func, x0, fprime=None, epsilon=.001 ... )
```

estimates the gradient at `x` by `(func( x + epsilon I ) - func(x)) / epsilon`.
Which is "best" for your application, though,
depends strongly on how smooth your function is, and how many variables.
Plain Nelder-Mead, `fmin`, is a good first choice -- slow but sure; 
unfortunately the scipy Nelder-Mead starts off with a fixed-size simplex, .05 / .00025 regardless of the scale of x.

I've heard that `fmin_tnc` in `scipy.optimize.tnc` is good:

```
fmin_tnc( func, x0, approx_grad=True, epsilon=.001 ... )  or
fmin_tnc( func_and_grad, x0 ... )  # func, your own estimated gradient
```

(fmin_tnc is ~ fmin_ncg with bound constraints, nice messages to see what's happening, somewhat different args.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not too familiar with what's available in SciPy, but the [Downhill Simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder-Mead_method) method (aka Nelder-Mead or the Amoeba method) frequently works well for multidimensional optimization.

Looking now at the [scipy documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html?highlight=nelder), it looks like it is available as an option in the `minimize()` function using the `method='Nelder-Mead'` argument.

Don't confuse it with the Simplex (Dantzig) algorithm for Linear Programming...

Comment: Also, as [fmin](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin) function